# Cell phone professionalism

Tags: employer-relations

My direct supervisor called me today on my cell phone for a new job I haven't started yet. She told me to save her cell phone number she called me off of. I'm pretty sure I will not be receiving a business cell phone. Does her action pass the threshold of professionalism? Am I obligated to save her number?

Comment: When do you start the job? If you're starting in less than a week is a bit different than if you still have a couple of week or more to my mind here.

Comment: Why would you *not* save your direct supervisor's number?

Comment: She is asking you to save her number - that's all. Don't think too much into it. Save it so that you know when she is calling and you can react appropriately.

Comment: If it does not meet that threshold, what do you propose to do?  Turn her in to her boss, at a job you have not started?  Why are you offended by this in the first place

Comment: I'm guessing that you're worried that this means your supervisor is going to be calling you a lot on your personal phone. Unless you've been given some indication that's going to happen, there's no reason to think that. She's not asking you to use your personal phone as a business phone, she's just making sure you can contact each other if you aren't able to use email for some reason.

Comment: That sounds like a good thing. What is it you're worried about?

Comment: I can't see a reason why you would not think this is positive.

Comment: Save her cell phone number. If you're still with your current employer, knowing what her number looks like will let you know when not to pick up. If you're worried about someone discovering/seeing that number on your phone, just file it under a different, but unique name, like "telemarketing", or "spam", "crazy grandma", or whatever.

Answer (score 33):

She  is giving you her phone number so you can reach her if you need to. This is courteous, it's good business operative, and it's an indication of trust that you won't use it inappropriately. Do save the number; you may need it someday.

Answer (score 6):

Your supervisor giving you his / her number and asking you to save it is actually a good sign, it means she / he is seeing you as someone who is going to be working with him / her for a period of time worth establishing a reliable communication channel (aka the phone) you should interpret it as that, and, to be honest, as someone working with subordinates you put a lot of thinking on who you *really* need to give your personal phone number to, and then only give it to those you consider worthy of a lot of trust.

Answer (score 4):

I am positive we talking about a job waiting for you to do, this is a courteous gesture with a clear direction of where to start from,you should should positively react and save it.